# The greatest prime factor of $2^n+1$

Tags: number-theory, fermat-numbers

Let $f(n)$ be the greatest prime factor of $2^n+1$

> Is it true that for any $c>0$ ,there is an integer $n>c$ such that $f(n+1)<f(n)$ ?

This is true if there are infinitely many Fermat primes:

If $n>1$ and $2^{2^n}+1=x^4+1$ is prime,then

$2^{2^n+2}+1=4x^4+1=(1-2x+2x^2)(1+2x+2x^2),\\ f(2^n+2)<1+2x+2x^2<x^4+1=f(2^n).$

Comment: We cannot rule out infinite many fermat primes, but it rather seems that $65537$ is the largest fermat prime.

Comment: I guess this is extremely difficult to solve. Good candidates should be the cases $n=2^k$

Comment: @Peter I'm looking for a proof without the assumption of the infinity of Fermat primes.

Comment: Currently, my largest solution is $n=257$, but I do not think that it is the last. Looking up the factorizations with factordb, we might find larger solutions.

Comment: In fact, $f(698)<f(697)$  (factordb) , I will look for larger solutions.

Comment: $f(1406)<f(1405)$

Comment: $f(2256)<f(2255)$

Comment: $f(2934)<f(2933)$ . It seems that we should rather concentrate on heuristics for infinite many solutions.

Comment: @lsr314 it is really tough to find numerically such number always! So, I think first you should show that 2ⁿ+1 can be prime for some sufficiently large n always,(I mean we can find such n always!), Then 2ⁿ⁺¹+1=2(2ⁿ+1)-1,like 2p-1 for prime p, clearly we know that 2p-1 is composite for almost many case! Then you got your answer! I think.

Comment: @Subhajit If 2^n+1 is prime then it's a  Fermat prime

Comment: @Subhajit This barely won't work, since it is extremely likely that only finite many such primes exist, it is still very likely (at least $10^9:1$) that we know them all.

Comment: And even for an expression like $n^2+1$ (which should produce infinite many primes) we cannot prove that infinite many primes are of that form. The only solved cases are the Dirichlet-case ($an+b$ with coprime $a,b$) and $a^2+b^4$ , the latter proven to produce infinite many primes by a man from Iceland.